# How to Insert DropDown Selection into MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to post the value chosen for a dropdown menu into my database table. But for some reason its not inputting the value into the database. I am trying to post `cat_id` into my database. So i use the code below to geenrate my dropdown list from values i alrady have in the database. Then below i have the function that inserts the info into the database. But for some reason its not working. I am suppose to put what is in `select name=""` right?

```
<select name="cat[<?=$row['pk_id']?>]">
              <?php $cat = dbConnect("SELECT * FROM category");
                    if(empty($row['cat_id'])){
                    ?>
                    <option value="">Select Category</option>
                    <?php
                    }
 
              ?>
                       
                  
              <?php while($cat_r = mysql_fetch_array($cat)){ 
              
              if($row['cat_id'] == $cat_r['cat_id']){
              ?>
              <option value="<?=$cat_r[cat_id]?>" selected="selected"><?=stripslashes($cat_r[cat_name])?></option>
              <?php
              continue;
              }
              
              ?>
             <option value="<?=$cat_r[cat_id]?>"><?=stripslashes($cat_r[cat_name])?></option>
<?php }  ?>
</select>
```

Here is my insert to MySQL

```
dbConnect("INSERT INTO post_info(add_to_random, show_home, source, display_vote_page, cat_id) values(1,1,1,0,cat[.$row['pk_id'].])");
```

Did i put something wrong here for the value for `cat_id`? I put cat[.$row['pk_id'].]) which is the `select name=""` for that dropdown list.

#### Code ported from comment:

```
if($_POST and $_POST['action'] == 'submit'){ 
  foreach($_POST as $k=>$v){
    $$k = $v;
  } 
  foreach($cat as $k=>$v){
    if($v =='') continue;
    dbConnect("UPDATE twit_info set cat_id=" . $v . " where pk_id =". $k ); 
  }
  if(count($pkid)>0){
    $pid = implode(',',$pkid); 
    dbConnect("UPDATE twit_info set add_to_vote = 1, display_vote_page = 1 where pk_id in(". $pid .")"); 
  }
}
```

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` to see what your form data posted looks like.  You will find something like `$_POST['cat'][123]`.  Then your quoting is incorrect in `dbConnect()`.  You have attempted to concatenate in `$cat[$row['pk_id']]` but have not closed your quotes.  To truly help you, we need to see _the rest_ of the code surrounding the INSERT, most importantly how you are retrieving `$cat` from the post.

Comment: I put this in `'"$cat[.$row['pk_id'].]"'` but i get the error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in

Comment: It will be something like `...'" . $cat[$row['pk_id']] . "'...`,  but we don't know for sure without seeing how you set `$cat`.

Comment: I have it setup as `$cat as $k=>$v`

Comment: @sonicool That doesn't really help us.  Please post the surrounding PHP code to that insert as I asked.

Comment: Hold im trying to insert it into a new page because its on another page i have coded ill show you whati  have there

Comment: `if($_POST and $_POST['action'] == 'submit'){ 
foreach($_POST as $k=>$v){
$$k = $v;
}
foreach($cat as $k=>$v){

 if($v =='') continue;
 
dbConnect("UPDATE twit_info set cat_id=" . $v . "  where pk_id =". $k );
}
if(count($pkid)>0){
$pid = implode(',',$pkid);

dbConnect("UPDATE twit_info set  add_to_vote = 1, display_vote_page = 1  where pk_id in(". $pid .")");
 }
}`

Comment: Im trying to work on it too as we speak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in your `foreach` loop, you are extracting all post keys into global variables via the variable variable `$$k` (I'll get to this in a second).  In your `dbConnect()` call, the quoting is incorrect. You should concatenate in `$cat`.

```
dbConnect("
  INSERT INTO post_info
    (add_to_random, show_home, source, display_vote_page, cat_id) 
    values(1,1,1,0, '" . mysql_real_escape_string($cat[$row['pk_id']]) . "')" );
```

I have added a call to `mysql_real_escape_string()`. This is necessary *at a minimum*, to protect all your queries from SQL injection.  Your other `UPDATE` statements are also vulnerable at this point and you *MUST* perform some escaping on them as well.

Regarding the extraction of `$_POST` into global variables - I highly recommend against this. You are in effect imitating the behavior of [`register_globals`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) which is considered very dangerous.  The danger comes in that it is possible for anyone to post *any* key to your form, in addition to the ones you actually expect to receive, potentially initializing another variable in your script to a value sent via `$_POST` when your script doesn't expect it.

Although I really just recommend operating on `$_POST` directly, rather than extracting to global variables, if you must extract them to globals, I advise you to use a whitelist of acceptable `$_POST` keys:

```
// Make an array of allowed keys
$good_keys = ('action', 'cat', 'otherformkey');
foreach($cat as $k=>$v){
  // Only extract if it is one of the allowed keys
  if($v =='' || !in_array($k, $good_keys) continue;

  // Cast to an integer
  $v = intval($v);
  $k = intval($k);
  // Non-integer strings will cast to zero, so don't do the db action.
  if ($v > 0 && $k > 0) {
    dbConnect("UPDATE twit_info set cat_id=" . $v . " where pk_id =". $k ); 
  }
  // For string values which are quoted in the SQL (unlike the int values above)
  // escape them with mysql_real_escape_string()
  // $v = mysql_real_escape_string($v)
}
```

Comment: Let me tlook at this hold on haha